# How can I trigger SonarLint Visual Studio plugin to update its configuration from the commandline?

Tags: msbuild, sonarlint

We want to ensure we are always using the latest rulesets from the SonarQube server. Is it possible to update the SonarLint rules when a solution is opened/built?

Or is there a way I can run the update from the commandline?